# Socket.io "Listeners is undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Sorry if i'm ignorant or there is an actual problem here. I am hosting a http server with node.js, and apon running the server I get the error

```
    C:\Users\Xander\Desktop\Website>node ./processes.js
C:\Users\Xander\Desktop\Website\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:
  var listeners = server.listeners('request').slice(0);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'listeners' of undefined
    at Server.attach
(C:\Users\Xander\Desktop\Website\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\server.js:423:25)
    at Function.attach (C:\Users\Xander\Desktop\Website\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\lib\engine.io.js:124:10)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (C:\Users\Xander\Desktop\Website\node_modules\socket.io\lib\index.js:228:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Xander\Desktop\Website\processes.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

This error has not occurred before and just recently came up. I've tried reinstalling socket.io, and personally editing the file. Though, to no avail. It fails every time. So i'll gladly take advice on how to fix this. Thank you for your time...

How its being used

```
//Vars
var http       = require('http');
var express    = require("express");
var app        = express();
var path       = require("path");
var connect    = require("connect");
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket     = io.listen(server);

//Defined port

const PORT = 8080;

//Connection handler

function handleRequest(request, response){  
response.end(request.url);
};

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Log all connections made


//Show .html file

app.get('/',function(req,res){  
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});

//Port to listen to

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace? It could be that something changed in one of your files which caused an error to trickle down?

Comment: I think we need to see more of the relevant code context.  Perhaps, how this module is loaded and called?  I suspect you're passing the wrong type of object to the socket.io constructor.  It should be a server object, but it's probably not.  Please show us that code.

Comment: Socket is being used in processes.js, i'll put the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of your code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

`server` is undefined.

---

You can probably change this:

```
app.listen(8080);
```

to this:

```
var server = app.listen(8080);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

And, get rid of these that are too early in your code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket     = io.listen(server);
```

And, remove these too since you're using Express as your server:

```
function handleRequest(request, response){  
    response.end(request.url);
};

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
```